# SDRAW is not working in my computer

Tags: lisp

i have installed `clisp` in my ubuntu machine. I am trying to use `sdraw` to display the cons structure. But this `SDRAW` is not working in my computer.I tried to use the examples given in the book `A gentle indtroduction to symbolic computation`. Can anybody tell me how can i enable it to work?

[edit]

i used following command

> (sdraw ' (alpha  (barvo) charlie))

i got following message

```
 *** - EVAL: undefined function SDRAW
```

Thanks

Comment: what does it mean 'it is not working'? Can you be more specific what happens when you try to use sdraw?

Comment: i have made the changes. i hope the above mentioned information will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes i finally got the answer. we need to load the file [`sdraw.generic`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Lisp/sdraw/) and we can have to load the file using the command.

```
>(load "sdraw.generic")
```

then use the `sdraw` command to display the cons art.

```
>BreakBreak 40 [45]> (sdraw '(1 2 (10)))

            [*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
             |        |        |
             v        v        v
             1        2       [*|*]--->NIL
                               |
                               v
                              10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run the generic version of `sdraw` as follow

```
CL-USER> (load "sdraw.generic")
CL-USER> (sdraw:sdraw '(a b c (d e) f))
```

That will produce output to terminal/REPL

[image: sdraw-generic]

But if you want the fancier or GUI version, [sdraw.gui](https://github.com/azzamsa/sdraw/blob/master/sdraw.gui)

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :clx)
CL-USER> (load "sdraw.gui")
CL-USER> (sdraw:sdraw '(a b (c d (e) f)))
```

With fancy result

[image]